# Чтение данных из БД блоками

Tags: c#, база-данных

В таблице БД очень большое количество строк, так что если считывать их все сразу в DataTable, система начинает сильно тормозить из-за нехватки памяти. Мне нет необходимости иметь в памяти все строки. Как можно считывать строки блоками, например, по 50000 строк? Планировал считывать данные построчно с помощью DataReader, но не нашел нормального способа скопировать текущую строку DataReader в DataTable (вариант с явной итерацией по колонкам не очень хорош). Решение, когда выборка каждый раз строится заново для нового блока, мне известно, но хотелось бы понять как решить задачу иначе.

Comment: Какую БД используете? В `PostgreSQL`, `MySQL` есть `LIMIT/OFFSET`. В `MSSQL` можно через `ROW_NUMBER()` добиться такого же поведения

Comment: MSSQL. Но вы предлагаете способ с перестроением запроса, а мне хотелось бы выполнить запрос один раз.

Comment: ну это не совсем перестроение. Для `MSSQL` я такое реализовывал через хранимку, в которую передавал два параметра: количество и смещение. Работало вполне себе хорошо

Comment: Не получится выполнять запрос один раз. Если вам нужно записать результат куда-то в файл, возможно, и получится. Курсор в базах данных однонаправленный.

Разве что прокатит вариант, с сохранением, в фоне, результата в файл. И отображать уже из него

Answer (score 5):

Таблицы с десятками, сотнями тысяч строк с большим количеством столбцов вы ни когда не сможете быстро отобразить. Таблицу с несколькими сотнями тысяч строк вы не сможете даже загрузить. Не хватит памяти.

Что бы работать с такими данными, нужно применить виртуализацию данных. Когда у вас, как бы, есть список из миллиона строк, но на самом деле, в памяти хранится не более сотни. А сами данные появляются/загружаются в момент обращения к ним.

Поддержку виртуализации данных следует включить и у контрола, отображающего данные.
Вот хорошая статья и пример работы с такими таблицами: http://habrahabr.ru/post/208792/

В дополнение. Из собственного опыта, как этот процесс можно ускорить, при таблице с количеством строк больше миллиона, и количеством столбцов больше десятка.

1. Перво-наперво, получаем количество строк в таблице запросом SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table
2. Выбираем необходимый блок данных SELECT id FROM table SKIP n TAKE count
3. Детализируем выбранные строки по id.

Таким образом мне удалось уменьшить время выборки данных до нескольких сотен миллисекунд, в не зависимости от того какой это блок первый или же последний

Comment: DataReader умеет извлекать данные построчно. Как мне заставить считывать записи из DataReader в DataTable?

Comment: Используйте лучше ADO.NET. Если его использовать нет возможности. То можно использовать SQLCommand, а там дальше через DataAdapter выгружаете в DataTable.

Что бы взять данные из DataReader. Нужно воспользоваться DataSet.Load. А DataSet уже указывать в DataTable

Comment: Метод Load разве считывает не все записи?

Comment: Честно, не помню. Но проблема в том, что курсор в базах данных однонаправленный. И нельзя прочитать сотую запись, а потом первую. И если вам нужна 100000я запись, он прочитает все 100000, что бы получить эту.